# JavaScript / jQuery Global onError Handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, coldfusion

I've been asked to add the [HopToad](http://www.hoptoadapp.com/pages/home) JavaScript Notifier to a site. The JavaScript can be seen [here](http://hoptoadapp.com/javascripts/notifier.js).

What I am wondering is if there is a way that I can set a global error handler for JavaScript / jQuery the way I can with ColdFusion, where any error that occurs, AJAX or just in a function, causes the HopToad.notify(e) function that I need to call.

I've already looked into the .error() and .ajaxError() calls but they dont seem to be what I am looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!-- //

function handleError() {
    return true;
}

window.onerror = handleError;
//-->
</script>
```